# Python abstract property() "Can't instantiate abstract class [] with abstract methods", but I did

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, abstract

I'm trying to create a base class with a number of abstract python properties, in python 3.7.

I tried it one way (see 'start' below) using the @property, @abstractmethod, @property.setter annotations.  This worked but it doesn't raise an exception if the subclass doesn't implement a setter.  That's the point of using @abstract to me, so that's no good.

So I tried doing it another way (see 'end' below) using two @abstractmethod methods and a 'property()', which is not abstract itself but uses those methods.  This approach generates an error when instantiating the subclass:

```
        # {TypeError}Can't instantiate abstract class FirstStep with abstract methods end
```

I'm clearly implementing the abstract methods, so I don't understand what it means.  The 'end' property is not marked @abstract, but if I comment it out, it does run (but I don't get my property).  I also added that test non-abstract method 'test_elapsed_time' to demonstrate I have the class structure and abstraction right (it works).

Any chance I'm doing something dumb, or is there some special behavior around property() that's causing this?

```
class ParentTask(Task):
    def get_first_step(self):
        # {TypeError}Can't instantiate abstract class FirstStep with abstract methods end
        return FirstStep(self)


class Step(ABC):
    #     __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
    def __init__(self, task):
        self.task = task

    # First approach.  Works, but no warnings if don't implement setter in subclass
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def start(self):
        pass

    @start.setter
    @abstractmethod
    def start(self, value):
        pass

    # Second approach.  "This method for 'end' may look slight messier, but raises errors if not implemented.
    @abstractmethod
    def get_end(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def set_end(self, value):
        pass

    end = property(get_end, set_end)

    def test_elapsed_time(self):
        return self.get_end() - self.start


class FirstStep(Step):
    @property
    def start(self):
        return self.task.start_dt

    # No warnings if this is commented out.
    @start.setter
    def start(self, value):
        self.task.start_dt = value

    def get_end(self):
        return self.task.end_dt

    def set_end(self, value):
        self.task.end_dt = value
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue with `start` on 3.7.4 or 3.8.5. [Simplified example with just `start`, no `*end`, and an empty definition of `FirstStep` raises](https://tio.run/##jY/PCsIwDIfvfYocNxi7eBME/4Av4AOUuqVY3NaSxMGefrbdRNGLOZQm34@vTZjk5ofNPLs@eBLgiVUgN0gRb/WIxM4P2g3Wl8qS78FcG1izh@Opij0LmUZ6jKJWNZ1hhotgKCIutwpitWhBR4kTrQvGzlYghu8rTZWGdZrBLiOVyT6QD0gyLd3XUy8ziyHJ2g9hiN9YJZnXjCJIf4oqGE33wB/fst3ZEUteMR1raAm8UTnPTw "Python 3 – Try It Online") I get `TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class FirstStep with abstract methods start`. This has worked since 3.3.

Comment: Oh, I see. You defined a getter but no setter, and you want both getter and setter to be required. Ignore me.

Comment: Yes @chepner answer seems to explain that part.  I'm still trying to digest the rest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect this is a bug in the interaction of abstract methods and properties.

In your base class, the following things happen, in order:

1. You define an abstract method named `start`.
2. You create a new property that uses the abstract method from 1) as its getter. The name `start` now refers to this property, with the only reference to the original name now held by `Self.start.fget`.
3. Python saves a temporary reference to `start.setter`, because the name `start` is about to be bound to yet another object.
4. You create a second abstract method named `start`
5. The reference from 3) is given the abstract method from 4) to define a new property to replace the once currently bound to the name `start`. This property has as its getter the method from 1 and as its setter the method from 4). Now `start` refers to this property; `start.fget` refers to the method from 1); `start.fset` refers to the method from 4).

At this point, you have a property, whose *component* functions are abstract methods. The property itself was not decorated as abstract, but the definition of `property.__isabstractmethod__` marks it as such because all its component methods are abstract. More importantly, you have the following entries in `Step.__abstractmethods__`:

1. `start`, the `property`
2. `end`, the `property`
3. `set_end`, the setter for `end`
4. `gen_end`, the getter for `end`

Note that the component functions for the `start` property are missing, because `__abstractmethods__` stores *names of*, not references to, things that need to be overriden. Using `property` and the resulting property's `setter` method as decorators repeatedly replace what the name `start` refers to.

Now, in your child class, you define a *new* property named `start`, shadowing the inherited property, which has *no* setter and a concrete method as its getter. At this point, it doesn't matter if you provide a setter for this property or not, because as far as the `abc` machinery is concerned, you have provided everything it asked for:

1. A concrete method for the name `start`
2. Concrete methods for the names `get_end` and `set_end`
3. Implicitly a concrete definition for the name `end`, because all of the underlying functions for the property `end` have been provided concrete definitions.

Comment: [The docs for `abstractproperty` (deprecated)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractproperty) document a replacement approach with just `@abstractmethod`+`@property`. The example given states outright that properties can be partially abstract (e.g. just the setter, not the getter in their example) and that you should need to overwrite only that part of the `property` (implying if you have multiple abstract components, you must overwrite all abstract components), the fact that it doesn't actually behave that way definitely constitutes a bug.

Comment: Apparently, there is [a closed bug for it](https://bugs.python.org/issue39707). Looks like the implication I read there isn't really there; you *can* overwrite individual elements by referencing the parent property, but if you make your own property (rather than borrowing from and overwriting bits of the parent property) it's always going to satisfy the requirements of the ABC, even if you omit important bits.

Comment: Accepted, as I think I get the gist of what's going on here based on this explanation.  Thanks... and to @ShadowRanger for the bug report find.

Answer (score 0):

@chepner answered and explained it well.  Based on that, I came up with a way around it that is... well... you decide.  Sneaky at best.  But it achieves my 3 main goals:

1. Raises exceptions for unimplemented setters in subclasses
2. Supports the python property semantics (vs. functions etc)
3. Avoids boilerplate re-declaring every property in every subclass which still might not have solved #1 anyway.

Just declare the abstract get/set functions in the base class (not the property).  Then add a @classmethod initializer to the base class that creates the actual properties using those abstract methods, but at that point, they'll be concrete methods on the subclass.

It's a one liner after the subclass declaration to init the properties.  Nothing enforces that call being made, so it's not ironclad.  Not a big savings in this example, but I'll have many properties.  The end results doesn't look as dirty as I thought it would.  Would like to hear comments or warnings of things I'm overlooking.

```
from abc import abstractmethod, ABC

class ParentTask(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.first_step = FirstStep(self)
        self.second_step = SecondStep(self)
        print(self.first_step.end)
        print(self.second_step.end)


class Step(ABC):
    def __init__(self, task):
        self.task = task

    @classmethod
    def init_properties(cls):
        cls.end = property(cls.get_end, cls.set_end)

    @abstractmethod
    def get_end(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def set_end(self, value):
        pass


class FirstStep(Step):
    def get_end(self):
        return 1

    def set_end(self, value):
        self.task.end = value


class SecondStep(Step):
    def get_end(self):
        return 2

    def set_end(self, value):
        self.task.end = value


FirstStep.init_properties()
SecondStep.init_properties()
ParentTask()
```