# force subclass to implement property python

Tags: python, inheritance, properties, subclass, abstract-methods

Tried the answer from [force-implementing-specific-attributes-in-subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59285990/force-implementing-specific-attributes-in-subclass-python)

But does not work. This code still passes with no errors.

```
#python version: 3.8.1
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class A(ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def pr(self):
        return 0
    
class B(A):
    def pr(self):# not a property.
        return 5
    
b = B()

print(b.pr())
```

So how can I force subclasses to implement specific properties(pr as above)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code passes with no errors because you have given a concrete implementation for the abstract method, in the subclass, and it looks (not sure) that it is the only thing `abc` cares about. Also if you override, there is no way to have the same decorators from the parent class applied automatically, you have to repeat the property decorator syntax.

The best threads I found about that are [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65224767/python-abstract-property-cant-instantiate-abstract-class-with-abstract-me) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335436/decorators-on-abstract-methods). Please read them fully.

Besides, there is a recent Python [bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue39707), that looks closed without solving (or is it re-opened?). Read the full thread there too. Interesting and related.